# Angular 6 npm run test command failed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, karma-coverage, angular-test

I am trying to execute angular test cases but I am getting disconnect error whenever I am executing it.

Currently I have more than 1500 test cases written so might be it is taking time to execute it so is there any way to fix the disconnect error while executing larger amount of test cases.

Following is the error I am getting while executing it.

```
26 02 2021 10:36:47.160:DEBUG [Chrome 88.0.4324.150 (Linux x86_64)]: Disconnected during run, waiting 910000ms for reconnecting.
26 02 2021 10:36:47.160:DEBUG [Chrome 88.0.4324.150 (Linux x86_64)]: EXECUTING -> EXECUTING_DISCONNECTED
26 02 2021 10:51:57.169:WARN [Chrome 88.0.4324.150 (Linux x86_64)]: Disconnected (0 times)reconnect failed before timeout of 910000ms (ping timeout)
26 02 2021 10:51:57.170:DEBUG [Chrome 88.0.4324.150 (Linux x86_64)]: EXECUTING_DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
```

I tried to to increase the wait time but still it didnt worked for me.

following is the command I ran:

```
ng test --code-coverage --watch=false --browsers=Chrome
```

And my Karma file config is as follows:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      config: {
        browserConsoleLogOptions: true,
      },
      captureConsole: true,
      mocha: {
        bail: true
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    // reporters: ['progress', 'mocha', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    captureTimeout: 210000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3, 
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 910000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout : 910000,
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

SO, Is there any solution to execute more than 1500 test cases in angular application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try updating your karma npm packages a bit, particularly `karma-chrome-launcher`.

Comment: sure @AliF50 will check it and let you know

Comment: Hi @AliF50 this solution also didnt worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Globally install version 6.2.9 of @angular/cli and scaffold a new Angular 6 project. Run npm test on this new scaffolded project and see if it works. If it does, see what it has in `karma.conf.js` and `package.json` and the version numbers in `package.json`. If it doesn't, then I suspect something is wrong with your system.

Here are the versions of `@angular/cli`: [Angular CLI versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli)

Comment: Thanks for quick help, I did same thing as you mentioned and I am able to run test cases properly without any issues till 700 test cases but once the test cases are gets increased then again same issue is occurred.

Comment: Try a different machine or I am thinking something is wrong within your 700th test case.

Comment: I tried with different machine and even commented some test cases to check whether its working or not but it failed again

Comment: Thanks Ali for the help, I am doing some trail and error basis on that, will check it and let you know I get any solution